# Cancel SSH Session to Server

Tags: server, ssh

I use SSH to manage a server on my local network.

```
ssh username@192.168.1.210
```

Which works great. When I am finished in the server I normally just X out the command line window which fires a prompt telling me a process is running and closing will kill it. Which is fine.

I would however prefer a command I can use to gracefully close the ssh connect and bring the command line back to my local machine.

Is there such a thing? Or is X-ing out of the window the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close the remote shell by running:

```
exit
```

Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: haha...exit. I should have thought of that. None the less I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Actually its : exit (to close the ssh session) and: exit (to close the running local terminal) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check the ESCAPE CHARACTERS section of 'man ssh'. The key sequence for disconnect is enter-tilde-period.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that. "~." tells me command not found.

Comment: @ryandlf press the two keys quickly